# Numeric Regex Expression for Detection Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am completely new to regex hence the long question.
I would like to know about the **regex expression codes to detect different types of numbers** in a html paragraph tag.

> 1. **Integer number** (eg: 0 , 1,000 , 1000 , 028, -1 , etc)
> 2. **Floating number** (eg: 2.3 , 2.13 , 0.18 , .18 , -1.2 , etc)
>
> *or regex that can **combine both 1. & 2. -- all integer and float number** together will be so good! I tried some solution in Stackoverflow but the results are always undefined/null, else not detectable already*
>
> 3. **Ratio** (eg: 1:3:4 detect as a whole if possible)
> 4. **Fractional number** (eg: 0/485 , 1/1006 , 2b/3 , etc)
> 5. **Percentage number** (eg: 15.5% , (15.5%) , 15% , 0.9%, .9%)

Also, would like to know if regex can **detect symbols and numbers together** in a whole (15.5% , 1:3:4), or must they be split into different parts before the detection of number can be performed (eg: 15.5 + % , 1 + : + 3 + : + 4 ) ?

These different expressions are meant to be written into **Javascript** code as different exceptions of cases later on. The expressions are planned to be used like the regex that detects basic integer in attached Javascript snippet below:

```
    var paragraphText = document.getElementById("detect").innerHTML;
    var allNumbers = paragraphText.match( /\d+/g ) + '';
    var numbersArray = allNumbers.split(',');

    for (i = 0; i < numbersArray.length; i++) { 
        //console.log(numbersArray[i]);
        numbersArray[i] = "<span>" + numbersArray[i] + "</span>";
        console.log(numbersArray[i]);
    }
    
    });
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: `match` returns and Array. Remove `+ ''` and loop through `allNumbers` itself.

Comment: how can you fractional number contain `b`?

Comment: @rock321987 as in I need an expression to let it has detection error or detect separately. not sure how to categorizes it hence put into fractional number since it is like 2/3*b ?? :/

Comment: bit of starter..check **[here](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3yX9/1)**

Comment: @rock321987 hmm... does this mean that this long expression will only take out these 2 numbers into array? So, in order to achieve the result like yours, I have to amend the remaining expressions below to have totally 0 match for those that I don't one? (I usually got 2 matches or more for strings I don't want) or it will only take in those with 1 complete match in a string?

Comment: its nothing but reordering same thing..that's why I am too lazy to write the complete expression

Comment: **[another](https://regex101.com/r/qZ3yX9/2)**

Comment: @rock321987 thanks for the 2 examples! I will try to understand it and complete the remaining expressions :) thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are simple implementations:

```
'2,13.00'.match(/[.,\d]+/g) // 1 & 2
'1:3:4'.match(/[:\d]+/g) // 3
'0/485'.match(/[\/\d]+/g) // 4
'15.5%'.match(/[.%\d]+/g) // 5
```

You can loop through them using `for` statement, and check if one is detected and break, or continue otherwise.

Comment: thanks for the implementations :) I just included -ve for the 1 & 2, does this means that i just have to add [+-] in front of /[.,\d]+/g for it to work?

Comment: Yes, you can make it as `/[+-]?[.,\d]+/g`. The question mark depends on whether you require a sign or not. If you require, then remove the question mark, otherwise you can leave it. Basically, question mark means optional.

Comment: Note : `string.match(/[.,\d]+/g)` matches `123abc456` and returns an array with `123` and `456`. If you dont want `123abc456` to match use `^` (string start) and `$` (string end) in the regex. For example: `string.match(/^[.,\d]+$/)`.

Comment: @Ghasan noted with thanks! :D trying possible cases now! ^^

Comment: @MadPiranha oh yes i don't want them to match, thanks for the tips! :D

Comment: Any tips on how to make /[\/\d]+/g to only detect one slash in fraction (1/4) and not (1/4/3/1...)? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Ghasan By the way, I use regex101 to test string. Want to know if the regular expression will take out only those with 1 match or also includes those with 2 matchs and above string (that I don't want)?

Comment: @Joysofyz, Try `number.match(/^[+-]?[\d]+\/[\d]+$/g)` to detect only one slash.

Answer (score 0):

```
For decimals numbers: 
 ->  ((?:\d+|)(?:\.|)(?:\d+))
For percentage numbers : It is the same as decimal numbers followed by % symbol 
 ->  ((?:\d+|)(?:\.|)(?:\d+))%
For whole numbers: the following regex would work and would exclude any decimal numbers as well, returning you just the integers
 ->  (^|[^\d.])\b\d+\b(?!\.\d)
For the ration requirement, I have created a complicated one, but you would get the entire ratio as a whole.
 -> (((?:\d+|)(?:\.|)(?:\d+)):)*((?:\d+|)(?:\.|)(?:\d+))
```